# Am I using update correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-update

What I am trying to say is:
"If RC.Expiration is greater than or equal to today's date and RC.DemoLicense is equal to 0 then set DemoTracking.Purchased to 1" I only need to look at entries where DT.Purchased is 0.

```
update WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking
set Purchased = 1
from WebCatalog.Published.RCompany RC
inner join WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking DT
    on RC.Link = DT.RCompanyLink and DT.Purchased = 0
where RC.Expiration >= GETDATE() and RC.DemoLicense = 0
```

Comment: I'd move `DT.Purchased = 0` into the where clause, but it's subjective, it will work the same anyway. At the first glance looks like your query should work correctly.

Comment: GetDate() returns a datetime which will cause you to miss records from earlier in the day.  To solve this problem, cast getdate() as a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
update WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking
set Purchased = 1
where Purchased = 0 and RCompanyLink in (select Link as RCompanyLink from WebCatalog.Published.RCompany where RC.Expiration >= GETDATE() and RC.DemoLicense = 0)
```